# Saying the word "Pig"

Tags: minhag, words

There seems to be a sensitivity among some people not to say the word "Pig". Aside from simple purity of speech, where does this come from? Is there a source?

Comment: Pesachim 3B mentions it https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.3b.5?with=all&lang=bi

Comment: The Gemara you quote simply supports clean speech. We find that the Gemara will use the term 'Davar Acher' in some places, but in others will use the word 'Chazir'.

Comment: The Gemara mentions a sensitivity to saying that word if it’s not necessary. Obviously there’s nothing with the word in of itself, its mentioned in the Torah

Comment: The Gemara seems to be speaking of the word 'Tamei', not 'Chazir'.

Comment: The story with Rav is about pig

Comment: I don't see the story you refer to.

Comment: There were these two students who were sitting before Rav and were weary from studying a complex issue. One of them said: This halakha we are studying is rendering us as tired as a tired [mesankan] something else, a euphemism for a pig. And the other one said: This halakha is rendering us as tired as a tired kid. Rav would not speak with that student who made reference to a pig, as one who speaks inappropriately is undoubtedly flawed in character.

Comment: @Chatzkel That might only suggest that it is inappropriate to compare oneself or other people to a pig, not that the word itself is inherently inappropriate. On the other hand, Chazal frequently describe a pig as "*davar acheir*" (e.g., in this very *sugya*), suggesting it is a more refined manner of speech to reference pigs euphemistically when possible.